# Why use double indirection? or Why use pointers to pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

When should a double indirection be used in C? Can anyone explain with a example?

What I know is that a double indirection is a pointer to a pointer.  Why would I need a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: Be careful; the phrase "double pointer" also refers to the type `double*`.

Comment: Take a note: answer to this question is different for C and C++ - do not add c+ tag to this very old question.

Comment: @BЈовић Though it's old question and old comment, what's the difference in the usage of double pointer between C and C++? After seeing your comment that they are different, I tried to give the answer by myself but still I see little difference in the usage of double pointers in C and C++.

Comment: can be used for jagged array of characters, ie, list of list where each list has different length

Answer (score 577, accepted):

If you want to have a list of characters (a word), you can use `char *word`

If you want a list of words (a sentence), you can use `char **sentence`

If you want a list of sentences (a monologue), you can use `char ***monologue`

If you want a list of monologues (a biography), you can use `char ****biography`

If you want a list of biographies (a bio-library), you can use `char *****biolibrary`

If you want a list of bio-libraries (a ??lol), you can use `char ******lol`

... ...

<sup>*yes, I know these might not be the best data structures*</sup>

---

Usage example with a very very very boring *lol*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int wordsinsentence(char **x) {
    int w = 0;
    while (*x) {
        w += 1;
        x++;
    }
    return w;
}

int wordsinmono(char ***x) {
    int w = 0;
    while (*x) {
        w += wordsinsentence(*x);
        x++;
    }
    return w;
}

int wordsinbio(char ****x) {
    int w = 0;
    while (*x) {
        w += wordsinmono(*x);
        x++;
    }
    return w;
}

int wordsinlib(char *****x) {
    int w = 0;
    while (*x) {
        w += wordsinbio(*x);
        x++;
    }
    return w;
}

int wordsinlol(char ******x) {
    int w = 0;
    while (*x) {
        w += wordsinlib(*x);
        x++;
    }
    return w;
}

int main(void) {
    char *word;
    char **sentence;
    char ***monologue;
    char ****biography;
    char *****biolibrary;
    char ******lol;

    //fill data structure
    word = malloc(4 * sizeof *word); // assume it worked
    strcpy(word, "foo");

    sentence = malloc(4 * sizeof *sentence); // assume it worked
    sentence[0] = word;
    sentence[1] = word;
    sentence[2] = word;
    sentence[3] = NULL;

    monologue = malloc(4 * sizeof *monologue); // assume it worked
    monologue[0] = sentence;
    monologue[1] = sentence;
    monologue[2] = sentence;
    monologue[3] = NULL;

    biography = malloc(4 * sizeof *biography); // assume it worked
    biography[0] = monologue;
    biography[1] = monologue;
    biography[2] = monologue;
    biography[3] = NULL;

    biolibrary = malloc(4 * sizeof *biolibrary); // assume it worked
    biolibrary[0] = biography;
    biolibrary[1] = biography;
    biolibrary[2] = biography;
    biolibrary[3] = NULL;

    lol = malloc(4 * sizeof *lol); // assume it worked
    lol[0] = biolibrary;
    lol[1] = biolibrary;
    lol[2] = biolibrary;
    lol[3] = NULL;

    printf("total words in my lol: %d\n", wordsinlol(lol));

    free(lol);
    free(biolibrary);
    free(biography);
    free(monologue);
    free(sentence);
    free(word);
}
```

Output:

```
total words in my lol: 243
```

Comment: Just wanted to point out that a `arr[a][b][c]` is not a `***arr`. Pointer of pointers use references of references, while `arr[a][b][c]` is stored as a usual array in row major order.

Comment: @pmg i can use char *ptr= "my sentence";   and pass ptr to function why ** then ?

Comment: @user143252 -- What if you have `"my sentence"`, `"his sentence"`, `"her sentence"`, and `"their sentence"`? You can do `char *ptr1 = "my sentence";` *etc*... but it's more comfortable to do an array of 5 (4 + NULL) pointers: `char *ptrs[5] = {"my sentence", "his sentence", ..., NULL}`. When you pass that array to a function (`foo(ptrs)`) the array is automatically converted to type `char**`!

Answer (score 220):

One reason is you want to change the value of the pointer passed to a function as the function argument, to do this you require pointer to a pointer.

In simple words, **Use `**` when you want to preserve (OR retain change in) the Memory-Allocation or Assignment even outside of a function call.** (So, Pass such function with double pointer arg.)

This may not be a very good example, but will show you the basic use:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void allocate(int **p)
{
    *p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
}

int main()
{
    int *p = NULL;
    allocate(&p);
    *p = 42;
    printf("%d\n", *p);
    free(p);
}
```

Comment: what would be different if allocate were `void allocate(int *p)` and you called it as `allocate(p)`?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Yes. The code will segfault. Please see Silviu's Answer.

Comment: @Asha what is the difference between allocate(p) and allocate(&p)?

Comment: @Asha - Can't we just return the pointer? If we must keep it void then whats a practical use-case of this scenario?

Comment: @user2979872 allocate(p): p is passed by value, and hence changes in function are not reflected in the main method.
allocate(&p): p is passed by reference, and hence the changes in p are reflected in the main method.

However, there is a catch. If allocate(p) is used and we change the value in the address pointed by b, then the changes will be reflected in main() for the value as the change happened at the memory location directly.
Just to reiterate, value change in p still will not be reflected.

Comment: OP stated that one reason to use ** is to change the value of a pointer passed to a function. Aren't pointers passed by reference/address so any changes to it will make "permanent" changes outside of the scope of the function? (change by accessing pointer address and dereferencing)

Answer (score 138):

- Let’s say you have a pointer. Its value is an address.
- but now you want to change that address.
- you could. by doing `pointer1 = pointer2`, you give pointer1 the address of pointer2.
- but! if you do that within a function, and you want the result to persist after the function is done, you need do some extra work. you need a new pointer3 just to point to pointer1. pass pointer3 to the function.
- here is an example. look at the output below first, to understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int c = 1;
    int d = 2;
    int e = 3;
    int * a = &c;
    int * b = &d;
    int * f = &e;
    int ** pp = &a;  // pointer to pointer 'a'

    printf("\n a's value: %x \n", a);
    printf("\n b's value: %x \n", b);
    printf("\n f's value: %x \n", f);
    printf("\n can we change a?, lets see \n");
    printf("\n a = b \n");
    a = b;
    printf("\n a's value is now: %x, same as 'b'... it seems we can, but can we do it in a function? lets see... \n", a);
    printf("\n cant_change(a, f); \n");
    cant_change(a, f);
    printf("\n a's value is now: %x, Doh! same as 'b'...  that function tricked us. \n", a);

    printf("\n NOW! lets see if a pointer to a pointer solution can help us... remember that 'pp' point to 'a' \n");
     printf("\n change(pp, f); \n");
    change(pp, f);
    printf("\n a's value is now: %x, YEAH! same as 'f'...  that function ROCKS!!!. \n", a);
    return 0;
}

void cant_change(int * x, int * z){
    x = z;
    printf("\n ----> value of 'a' is: %x inside function, same as 'f', BUT will it be the same outside of this function? lets see\n", x);
}

void change(int ** x, int * z){
    *x = z;
    printf("\n ----> value of 'a' is: %x inside function, same as 'f', BUT will it be the same outside of this function? lets see\n", *x);
}
```

Here is the output: (**read this first**)

```
 a's value: bf94c204

 b's value: bf94c208 

 f's value: bf94c20c 

 can we change a?, lets see 

 a = b 

 a's value is now: bf94c208, same as 'b'... it seems we can, but can we do it in a function? lets see... 

 cant_change(a, f); 

 ----> value of 'a' is: bf94c20c inside function, same as 'f', BUT will it be the same outside of this function? lets see

 a's value is now: bf94c208, Doh! same as 'b'...  that function tricked us. 

 NOW! lets see if a pointer to a pointer solution can help us... remember that 'pp' point to 'a' 

 change(pp, f); 

 ----> value of 'a' is: bf94c20c inside function, same as 'f', BUT will it be the same outside of this function? lets see

 a's value is now: bf94c20c, YEAH! same as 'f'...  that function ROCKS!!!.
```

Comment: This is a great answer and really helped me visualize the purpose and usefulness of a double pointer.

Comment: @Justin did you check out my answer above this one? its cleaner :)

Comment: Great answer, just lacks to explain that <code>void cant_change(int * x, int * z)</code> fails because its' parameters are just new local scoped pointers that are initialized likewise a and f pointers (so they are not the same as a and f).

Comment: Simple? Really? ;)

Comment: this answer really explains one of the most common use of pointer to pointers, thanks!

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 71):

Adding to [Asha's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/392315/asha) response, if you use single pointer to the example bellow (e.g. alloc1() ) you will lose the reference to the memory allocated inside the function.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void alloc2(int** p) {
    *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    **p = 10;
}

void alloc1(int* p) {
    p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p = 10;
}

int main(){
    int *p = NULL;
    alloc1(p);
    //printf("%d ",*p);//undefined
    alloc2(&p);
    printf("%d ",*p);//will print 10
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

The reason it occurs like this is that in `alloc1` the pointer is passed in by value. So, when it is reassigned to the result of the `malloc` call inside of `alloc1`, the change does not pertain to code in a different scope.

Comment: What happens if p is static integer pointer? Getting Segmentation fault.

Comment: `free(p)` isn't enough, you need to `if(p) free(*p)` as well

Comment: @ShijingLv: No. `*p` evaluates to an `int` holding the value of 10 , passing this  `int` to free()` is a bad idea.

Comment: The allocation done in `alloc1()` introduces a memory leak. The pointer value to be passed  free is lost by returning from the function.

Comment: No (!) need to cast the result of malloc in C.

Comment: would it solve the problem with memory leak? `int* alloc1(int* p) { p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); *p = 10; return p}` of course, makes little sense because you don't need to pass anoything to such a function

Answer (score 27):

**1. Basic Concept -**

When you declare as follows : -

**1. char *ch -    (called character pointer)**
- ch contains the address of a single character.
- (*ch) will dereference to the value of the character..

**2. char **ch -**
'ch' contains the address of an Array of character pointers. (as in 1)
'*ch' contains the address of a single character. (Note that it's different from 1, due to difference in declaration).
(**ch) will dereference to the exact value of the character..

*Adding more pointers expand the dimension of a datatype, from character to string, to array of strings, and so on... You can relate it to a 1d, 2d, 3d matrix..*

**So, the usage of pointer depends upon how you declare it.**

Here is a simple code..

```
int main()
{
    char **p;
    p = (char **)malloc(100);
    p[0] = (char *)"Apple";      // or write *p, points to location of 'A'
    p[1] = (char *)"Banana";     // or write *(p+1), points to location of 'B'

    cout << *p << endl;          //Prints the first pointer location until it finds '\0'
    cout << **p << endl;         //Prints the exact character which is being pointed
    *p++;                        //Increments for the next string
    cout << *p;
}
```

**2. Another Application of Double Pointers -**
(this would also cover pass by reference)

Suppose you want to update a character from a function. If you try the following : -

```
void func(char ch)
{
    ch = 'B';
}

int main()
{
    char ptr;
    ptr = 'A';
    printf("%c", ptr);

    func(ptr);
    printf("%c\n", ptr);
}
```

The output will be AA. This doesn't work, as you have "Passed By Value" to the function.

**The correct way to do that would be -**

```
void func( char *ptr)        //Passed by Reference
{
    *ptr = 'B';
}

int main()
{
    char *ptr;
    ptr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1);
    *ptr = 'A';
    printf("%c\n", *ptr);

    func(ptr);
    printf("%c\n", *ptr);
}
```

Now extend this requirement for updating a string instead of character.
For this, you need to receive the parameter in the function as a double pointer.

```
void func(char **str)
{
    strcpy(str, "Second");
}

int main()
{
    char **str;
    // printf("%d\n", sizeof(char));
    *str = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);          //Can hold 10 character pointers
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1);         //Each pointer can point to a memory of 1 character.
    }

    strcpy(str, "First");
    printf("%s\n", str);
    func(str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

In this example, method expects a double pointer as a parameter to update the value of a string.

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *ptr = 0;
    ptr = malloc(255); // allocate some memory
    strcpy( ptr, "Stack Overflow Rocks..!!");
    printf("%s\n", ptr);
    printf("%d\n",strlen(ptr));
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}`  But you can do it without using double pointer too.

Comment: "*char **ch -
'ch' contains the address of an Array of character pointers.*" No, it contains the address of the 1st element of an array of `char` pointers. A pointer to an array of `char*` would be typed for example like this: `char(*(*p)[42])` defines `p` as pointer to an array of 42 pointer to `char`.

Comment: The last snippet is completely broken. For starters: Here`*str = ...` `str` is dereferenced uninitialised invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: This `malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);` does not allocate room for 10 pointer to `char` but for 10 `char` only..

Comment: This loop `for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        str = ... ` misses to use the index `i`.

Comment: Here `void func(char **str)
{
    strcpy(str, "Second"); ...` the wrong type is passed to `strcpy()`. Same for the two calls to `printf()` in `main()`.

Comment: No (!) need to cast the result of malloc in C.

Comment: The loop ``for(i=0;i<10;i++)  { str = ...`` should be  ** ``for(i=0;i<10;i++)  { str[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1); ``**

Answer (score 26):

I saw a very good example today, from [this blog post](http://wordaligned.org/articles/two-star-programming), as I summarize below.

Imagine you have a structure for nodes in a linked list, which probably is

```
typedef struct node
{
    struct node * next;
    ....
} node;
```

Now you want to implement a `remove_if` function, which accepts a removal criterion `rm` as one of the arguments and traverses the linked list: if an entry satisfies the criterion (something like `rm(entry)==true`), its node will be removed from the list. In the end, `remove_if` returns the head (which may be different from the original head) of the linked list.

You may write

```
for (node * prev = NULL, * curr = head; curr != NULL; )
{
    node * const next = curr->next;
    if (rm(curr))
    {
        if (prev)  // the node to be removed is not the head
            prev->next = next;
        else       // remove the head
            head = next;
        free(curr);
    }
    else
        prev = curr;
    curr = next;
}
```

as your `for` loop. The message is, **without double pointers, you have to maintain a `prev` variable to re-organize the pointers**, and handle the two different cases.

But with double pointers, you can actually write

```
// now head is a double pointer
for (node** curr = head; *curr; )
{
    node * entry = *curr;
    if (rm(entry))
    {
        *curr = entry->next;
        free(entry);
    }
    else
        curr = &entry->next;
}
```

You don't need a `prev` now because **you can directly modify what `prev->next` pointed to**.

To make things clearer, let's follow the code a little bit. During the removal:

1. if `entry == *head`: it will be `*head (==*curr) = *head->next` -- `head` now points to the pointer of the new heading node. You do this by directly changing `head`'s content to a new pointer.
2. if `entry != *head`: similarly, `*curr` is what `prev->next` pointed to, and now points to `entry->next`.

No matter in which case, you can re-organize the pointers in a unified way with double pointers.

Answer (score 19):

Pointers to pointers also come in handy as "handles" to memory where you want to pass around a "handle" between functions to re-locatable memory.  That basically means that the function can change the memory that is being pointed to by the pointer inside the handle variable, and every function or object that is using the handle will properly point to the newly relocated (or allocated) memory.  Libraries like to-do this with "opaque" data-types, that is data-types were you don't have to worry about what they're doing with the memory being pointed do, you simply pass around the "handle" between the functions of the library to perform some operations on that memory ... the library functions can be allocating and de-allocating the memory under-the-hood without you having to explicitly worry about the process of memory management or where the handle is pointing.

For instance:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned char** handle_type;

//some data_structure that the library functions would work with
typedef struct 
{
    int data_a;
    int data_b;
    int data_c;
} LIB_OBJECT;

handle_type lib_create_handle()
{
    //initialize the handle with some memory that points to and array of 10 LIB_OBJECTs
    handle_type handle = malloc(sizeof(handle_type));
    *handle = malloc(sizeof(LIB_OBJECT) * 10);

    return handle;
}

void lib_func_a(handle_type handle) { /*does something with array of LIB_OBJECTs*/ }

void lib_func_b(handle_type handle)
{
    //does something that takes input LIB_OBJECTs and makes more of them, so has to
    //reallocate memory for the new objects that will be created

    //first re-allocate the memory somewhere else with more slots, but don't destroy the
    //currently allocated slots
    *handle = realloc(*handle, sizeof(LIB_OBJECT) * 20);

    //...do some operation on the new memory and return
}

void lib_func_c(handle_type handle) { /*does something else to array of LIB_OBJECTs*/ }

void lib_free_handle(handle_type handle) 
{
    free(*handle);
    free(handle); 
}


int main()
{
    //create a "handle" to some memory that the library functions can use
    handle_type my_handle = lib_create_handle();

    //do something with that memory
    lib_func_a(my_handle);

    //do something else with the handle that will make it point somewhere else
    //but that's invisible to us from the standpoint of the calling the function and
    //working with the handle
    lib_func_b(my_handle); 

    //do something with new memory chunk, but you don't have to think about the fact
    //that the memory has moved under the hood ... it's still pointed to by the "handle"
    lib_func_c(my_handle);

    //deallocate the handle
    lib_free_handle(my_handle);

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps,

Jason

Comment: What is the reason for the handle type being unsigned char**? Would void** work just as well?

Comment: `unsigned char` is specifically used because we're storing a pointer to binary data that will be represented as raw bytes.  Using `void` will require a cast at some point, and is generally not as readable as to the intent of what is being done.

Answer (score 9):

A little late to the party, but hopefully this will help someone.

In C arrays always allocate memory on the stack, thus a function can't return
a (non-static) array due to the fact that memory allocated on the stack
gets freed automatically when the execution reaches the end of the current block.
That's really annoying when you want to deal with two-dimensional arrays
(i.e. matrices) and implement a few functions that can alter and return matrices.
To achieve this, you could use a pointer-to-pointer to implement a matrix with
dynamically allocated memory:

```
/* Initializes a matrix */
double** init_matrix(int num_rows, int num_cols){
    // Allocate memory for num_rows float-pointers
    double** A = calloc(num_rows, sizeof(double*));
    // return NULL if the memory couldn't allocated
    if(A == NULL) return NULL;
    // For each double-pointer (row) allocate memory for num_cols floats
    for(int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++){
        A[i] = calloc(num_cols, sizeof(double));
        // return NULL if the memory couldn't allocated
        // and free the already allocated memory
        if(A[i] == NULL){
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
                free(A[j]);
            }
            free(A);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return A;
}
```

Here's an illustration:

```
double**       double*           double
             -------------       ---------------------------------------------------------
   A ------> |   A[0]    | ----> | A[0][0] | A[0][1] | A[0][2] | ........ | A[0][cols-1] |
             | --------- |       ---------------------------------------------------------
             |   A[1]    | ----> | A[1][0] | A[1][1] | A[1][2] | ........ | A[1][cols-1] |
             | --------- |       ---------------------------------------------------------
             |     .     |                                    .
             |     .     |                                    .
             |     .     |                                    .
             | --------- |       ---------------------------------------------------------
             |   A[i]    | ----> | A[i][0] | A[i][1] | A[i][2] | ........ | A[i][cols-1] |
             | --------- |       ---------------------------------------------------------
             |     .     |                                    .
             |     .     |                                    .
             |     .     |                                    .
             | --------- |       ---------------------------------------------------------
             | A[rows-1] | ----> | A[rows-1][0] | A[rows-1][1] | ... | A[rows-1][cols-1] |
             -------------       ---------------------------------------------------------
```

The double-pointer-to-double-pointer `A` points to the first element `A[0]` of a
memory block whose elements are double-pointers itself. You can imagine these
double-pointers as the rows of the matrix. That's the reason why every
double-pointer allocates memory for num_cols elements of type double.
Furthermore `A[i]` points to the i-th row, i.e. `A[i]` points to `A[i][0]` and
that's just the first double-element of the memory block for the i-th row.
Finally, you can access the element in the i-th row
and j-th column easily with `A[i][j]`.

Here's a complete example that demonstrates the usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

/* Initializes a matrix */
double** init_matrix(int num_rows, int num_cols){
    // Allocate memory for num_rows double-pointers
    double** matrix = calloc(num_rows, sizeof(double*));
    // return NULL if the memory couldn't allocated
    if(matrix == NULL) return NULL;
    // For each double-pointer (row) allocate memory for num_cols
    // doubles
    for(int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++){
        matrix[i] = calloc(num_cols, sizeof(double));
        // return NULL if the memory couldn't allocated
        // and free the already allocated memory
        if(matrix[i] == NULL){
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
                free(matrix[j]);
            }
            free(matrix);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}

/* Fills the matrix with random double-numbers between -1 and 1 */
void randn_fill_matrix(double** matrix, int rows, int cols){
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j){
            matrix[i][j] = (double) rand()/RAND_MAX*2.0-1.0;
        }
    }
}


/* Frees the memory allocated by the matrix */
void free_matrix(double** matrix, int rows, int cols){
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        free(matrix[i]);
    }
    free(matrix);
}

/* Outputs the matrix to the console */
void print_matrix(double** matrix, int rows, int cols){
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            printf(" %- f ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}


int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int m = 3, n = 3;
    double** A = init_matrix(m, n);
    randn_fill_matrix(A, m, n);
    print_matrix(A, m, n);
    free_matrix(A, m, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nein. Please read this :  https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2014/09/08/dont-use-fake-matrices/ . Now come back and refactor your code.  I hope I am not annoying.

Comment: This is also not true: "n C arrays always allocate memory on the stack...", as you just showed in your post.

Answer (score 8):

Strings are a great example of uses of double pointers. The string itself is a pointer, so any time you need to point to a string, you'll need a double pointer.

Answer (score 8):

## Simple example that you probably have seen many times before

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

In the second parameter you have it: pointer to pointer to char.

Note that the pointer notation (`char* c`) and the array notation (`char c[]`) are interchangeable in function arguments. So you could also write `char *argv[]`. In other words `char *argv[]` and `char **argv` are interchangeable.

What the above represents is in fact an array of character sequences (the command line arguments that are given to a program at startup).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3024202/4486783) for more details about the above function signature.

Comment: *"pointer notation (`char* c`) and the array notation (`char c[]`) are interchangeable"* (and have the same exact meaning) **in function arguments**. They are different however outside function arguments.

Answer (score 7):

For example, you might want to make sure that when you free the memory of something you set the pointer to null afterwards.

```
void safeFree(void** memory) {
    if (*memory) {
        free(*memory);
        *memory = NULL;
    }
}
```

When you call this function you'd call it with the address of a pointer

```
void* myMemory = someCrazyFunctionThatAllocatesMemory();
safeFree(&myMemory);
```

Now `myMemory` is set to NULL and any attempt to reuse it will be very obviously wrong.

Comment: it should be `if(*memory)` and `free(*memory);`

Comment: Good point, signal loss between brain and keyboard.  I've edited it to make a bit more sense.

Comment: Why can't we do the following ...  void safeFree(void* memory) {
    if (memory) {
        free(memory);
        memory = NULL;
    }
}

Comment: @Peter_pk Assigning memory to null wouldn't help because you've got passed a pointer by value, not by reference (hence the example of a pointer to a pointer).

Answer (score 4):

Why double pointers?

The objective is to change what studentA points to, using a function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct Person{
    char * name;
} Person; 

/**
 * we need a ponter to a pointer, example: &studentA
 */
void change(Person ** x, Person * y){
    *x = y; // since x is a pointer to a pointer, we access its value: a pointer to a Person struct.
}

void dontChange(Person * x, Person * y){
    x = y;
}

int main()
{

    Person * studentA = (Person *)malloc(sizeof(Person));
    studentA->name = "brian";

    Person * studentB = (Person *)malloc(sizeof(Person));
    studentB->name = "erich";

    /**
     * we could have done the job as simple as this!
     * but we need more work if we want to use a function to do the job!
     */
    // studentA = studentB;

    printf("1. studentA = %s (not changed)\n", studentA->name);

    dontChange(studentA, studentB);
    printf("2. studentA = %s (not changed)\n", studentA->name);

    change(&studentA, studentB);
    printf("3. studentA = %s (changed!)\n", studentA->name);

    return 0;
}

/**
 * OUTPUT:
 * 1. studentA = brian (not changed)
 * 2. studentA = brian (not changed)
 * 3. studentA = erich (changed!)
 */
```

Comment: No (!) need to cast the result of malloc in C.

Comment: Wouldn't just using     *x = *y; work in your dontChange function?

Answer (score 3):

For instance if you want random access to noncontiguous data.

```
p -> [p0, p1, p2, ...]  
p0 -> data1
p1 -> data2
```

-- in C

```
T ** p = (T **) malloc(sizeof(T*) * n);
p[0] = (T*) malloc(sizeof(T));
p[1] = (T*) malloc(sizeof(T));
```

You store a pointer `p` that points to an array of pointers. Each pointer points to a piece of data.

If `sizeof(T)` is big it may not be possible to allocate a contiguous block (ie using malloc) of `sizeof(T) * n` bytes.

Comment: No (!) need to cast the result of malloc in C.

Answer (score 3):

One thing I use them for constantly is when I have an array of objects and I need to perform lookups (binary search) on them by different fields.
I keep the original array...

```
int num_objects;
OBJECT *original_array = malloc(sizeof(OBJECT)*num_objects);
```

Then make an array of sorted pointers to the objects.

```
int compare_object_by_name( const void *v1, const void *v2 ) {
  OBJECT *o1 = *(OBJECT **)v1;
  OBJECT *o2 = *(OBJECT **)v2;
  return (strcmp(o1->name, o2->name);
}

OBJECT **object_ptrs_by_name = malloc(sizeof(OBJECT *)*num_objects);
  int i = 0;
  for( ; i<num_objects; i++)
    object_ptrs_by_name[i] = original_array+i;
  qsort(object_ptrs_by_name, num_objects, sizeof(OBJECT *), compare_object_by_name);
```

You can make as many sorted pointer arrays as you need, then use a binary search on the sorted pointer array to access the object you need by the data you have.  The original array of objects can stay unsorted, but each pointer array will be sorted by their specified field.

Answer (score 3):

The following is a very simple C++ example that shows that if you want to use a function to set a pointer to point to an object, **you need a pointer to a pointer**. Otherwise, **the pointer will keep reverting to null**.

(A C++ answer, but I believe it's the same in C.)

(Also, for reference: Google("pass by value c++") = "By default, arguments in C++ are passed by value. When an argument is passed by value, the argument's value is copied into the function's parameter.")

So we want to set the pointer `b` equal to the string `a`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void Function_1(std::string* a, std::string* b) {
  b = a;
  std::cout << (b == nullptr);  // False
}

void Function_2(std::string* a, std::string** b) {
  *b = a;
  std::cout << (b == nullptr);  // False
}

int main() {
  std::string a("Hello!");
  std::string* b(nullptr);
  std::cout << (b == nullptr);  // True

  Function_1(&a, b);
  std::cout << (b == nullptr);  // True

  Function_2(&a, &b);
  std::cout << (b == nullptr);  // False
}

// Output: 10100
```

What happens at the line `Function_1(&a, b);`?

- The "value" of `&main::a` (an address) is copied into the parameter `std::string* Function_1::a`. Therefore `Function_1::a` is a pointer to (i.e. the memory address of) the string `main::a`.
- The "value" of `main::b` (an address in memory) is copied into the parameter `std::string* Function_1::b`. Therefore there are now 2 of these addresses in memory, both null pointers. At the line `b = a;`, the local variable `Function_1::b` is then changed to equal `Function_1::a` (= `&main::a`), but the variable `main::b` is unchanged. After the call to `Function_1`, `main::b` is still a null pointer.

What happens at the line `Function_2(&a, &b);`?

- The treatment of the `a` variable is the same: within the function, `Function_2::a` is the address of the string `main::a`.
- But the variable `b` is now being passed as a pointer to a pointer. The "value" of `&main::b` (the **address of the pointer** `main::b`) is copied into `std::string** Function_2::b`. Therefore within Function_2, dereferencing this as `*Function_2::b` will access and modify `main::b` . So the line `*b = a;` is actually setting `main::b` (an address) equal to `Function_2::a` (= address of `main::a`) which is what we want.

**If you want to use a function to modify a thing, be it an object or an address (pointer), you have to pass in a pointer to that thing.** The thing that you *actually* pass in cannot be modified (in the calling scope) because a local copy is made.

(An exception is if the parameter is a reference, such as `std::string& a`. But usually these are `const`. Generally, if you call `f(x)`, if `x` is an object you should be able to assume that `f` *won't* modify `x`. But if `x` is a pointer, then you should assume that `f` *might* modify the object pointed to by `x`.)

Comment: C++ code to answer a C question is not the best idea.

Answer (score 2):

In `C language` a string is an array of characters ending with `null` value (`'\0'`):

```
char str1[] = { 'H','i','\0'};
```

which is the same as

```
char *str1 = (char[]){ 'H','i','\0'};
```

or similar to

```
char *str1 = "Hi";
```

where `str1` is a pointer to the memory address of the first element of the array:

```
Type [var]  | Value | Memory address |
char        |    'H'|            100 | <--┐  
char        |    'i'|            108 |    |
char        |    \0 |            116 |    |
                    |            ...      |      
char *str1  |   100 |            180 |    |
                 └------------------------┘
```

## Array of pointers

Consider two pointers, each representing a string:

```
char *str1 = (char[]){ 'H','i','\0'};
char *str2 = (char[]){ 'S','O','!','\0'};
```

Sometimes, passing an array of strings to a function is necessary, for example, after splitting a sentence on strings by a space character. A string variable is a pointer, and an array of strings will be an *array of pointers*, or a *pointer-to-pointer*:

```
char **p2p = (char*[]){ str1, str2 };
```

```
Type [var]  | Value | Memory address |
char        |    'H'|            100 | <--┐
char        |    'i'|            108 |    |
char        |    \0 |            116 |    |
                    |            ...      |
char *str1  |   100 |            180 |    |
                 └------------------------┤    
char        |    'S'|            200 |    |<--┐ 
char        |    'O'|            208 |    |   |
char        |    '!'|            216 |    |   |
char        |    \0 |            222 |    |   |
                    |            ... |    |   |
char *str2  |   200 |            240 |    |   |
                 └------------------------┤---┤
                    |            ... |    |   |
char *      |   100 |            320 |    |   |<--┐
                 └------------------------┘   |   | 
char *      |   200 |            384 |        |   |
                 └----------------------------┘   |
                    |            ... |            |
char **p2p  |   320 |            480 |            |
                 └--------------------------------┘
```

This is the exact reason why command arguments in C are passed as a point-to-pointer:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { }
//or
int main(int argc, char **argv) { }
```

## Function parameters

Every parameter in the C function call is placed in a stack occupying its memory, even when it is a pointer.

```
void func(char *str_par)
{
    // ...  
}

int main()
{
   char *str_arg = "Hi";
   func(str_arg);
   return 0;
}
```

The important note is that the argument `str_arg` value is copied to the parameter `str_par`. They are both pointers holding the same value but occupying distinct memory addresses.

```
Varibale       | Value | Memory address |
               |    'H'|            100 | <--┐   <--┐
               |    'i'|            108 |    |      |
               |    \0 |            116 |    |      |
                       |            ...      |      |      
char *str_arg  |   100 |            180 |    |      |    
                    └------------------------┘      | 
char *str_par  |   100 |            300 |           |
                    └-------------------------------┘
```

Sometimes, there is a need to change the argument pointer `str_arg` to a new value. An attempt to do so inside the function will fail because only the value of the `str_par` will be changed.

```
char *glb_str = "StackOverflow";

void func(char *str_par)
{
    str_par = glb_str; 
}

int main()
{
   char *str_arg = "Hi";
   func(str_arg);
   // str_arg points to the same "Hi" array

   return 0;
}
```

```
Varibale       | Value | Memory address |
               |    'H'|            100 | <--┐
               |    'i'|            108 |    |      
               |    \0 |            116 |    |      
                       |            ...      |            
char *str_arg  |   100 |            180 |    |          
                    └------------------------┘       
char *str_par  |  9000 |            300 |           
                    └------------------------┐
char *glb_str  |  ...  |           9000 | <--┘
```

The solution is to use a *pointer-to-pointer*:

```
char *glb_str = "StackOverflow";

void func(char **p2p_str)
{
    *p2p_str = glb_str; 
}

int main()
{
   char *str_arg = "Hi";
   func(&str_arg);
   // str_arg is now changed to point to glb_str ("StackOverflow")

   return 0;
}
```

it becomes possible to change the passed pointer argument to any memory address (marked with `x`):

```
Varibale       | Value | Memory address |
               |    'H'|            100 | 
               |    'i'|            108 |        
               |    \0 |            116 |        
                       |            ...                
char *str_arg  |    x  |            180 |  <--┐      
                                              |
char **pp_str  |   180 |            300 |     | 
                    └-------------------------┘
```

```
Varibale       | Value | Memory address |
               |    'H'|            100 | 
               |    'i'|            108 |        
               |    \0 |            116 |        
                       |            ...                
char *str_arg  |  9000 |            180 |                                                     
                    └------------------------┐
char *glb_str  |  ...  |           9000 | <--┘
```

This is also useful when there is a need to reserve a new heap memory via `malloc/calloc` calls inside a function.

It is the same idea when you must pass and change a character value with `int i` => `int *ptr_i`. Adding one more layer of redirection results in a double pointer: `char *ptr_chars` => `char **ptr_ptr_chars`.

---

P.S. C runtime uses distinct memory segments for Code, Data, Stack, and Heap. The examples have simplified memory addresses for brevity.

Answer (score 1):

Compare modifying **value of variable** versus modifying **value of pointer**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void changeA(int (*a))
{
  (*a) = 10;
}

void changeP(int *(*P))
{
  (*P) = malloc(sizeof((*P)));
}

int main(void)
{
  int A = 0;

  printf("orig. A = %d\n", A);
  changeA(&A);
  printf("modi. A = %d\n", A);

  /*************************/

  int *P = NULL;

  printf("orig. P = %p\n", P);
  changeP(&P);
  printf("modi. P = %p\n", P);

  free(P);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This helped me to avoid returning value of pointer when the pointer was modified by the called function (used in singly linked list).

OLD (bad):

```
int *func(int *P)
{
  ...
  return P;
}

int main(void)
{
  int *pointer;
  pointer = func(pointer);
  ...
}
```

NEW (better):

```
void func(int **pointer)
{
  ...
}

int main(void)
{
  int *pointer;
  func(&pointer);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers here are more or less related to application programming. Here is an example from embedded systems programming. For example below is an excerpt from the reference manual of NXP's Kinetis KL13 series microcontroller, this code snippet is used to run bootloader, which resides in ROM, from firmware:

"
To get the address of the entry point, the user application reads the word containing the pointer to the bootloader API tree at offset 0x1C of the bootloader's vector table. The vector table is placed at the base of the bootloader's address range, which for the ROM is 0x1C00_0000. Thus, the API tree pointer is at address 0x1C00_001C.

The bootloader API tree is a structure that contains pointers to other structures, which have the function and data addresses for the bootloader. The bootloader entry point is always the first word of the API tree.
"

```
uint32_t runBootloaderAddress;
void (*runBootloader)(void * arg);
// Read the function address from the ROM API tree.
runBootloaderAddress = **(uint32_t **)(0x1c00001c);
runBootloader = (void (*)(void * arg))runBootloaderAddress;
// Start the bootloader.
runBootloader(NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used double pointers today while I was programming something for work, so I can answer why we had to use them (it's the first time I actually had to use double pointers). We had to deal with real time encoding of frames contained in buffers which are members of some structures. In the encoder we had to use a pointer to one of those structures. The problem was that our pointer was being changed to point to other structures from another thread. In order to use the current structure in the encoder, I had to use a double pointer, in order to point to the pointer that was being modified in another thread. It wasn't obvious at first, at least for us, that we had to take this approach. A lot of address were printed in the process :)).

You SHOULD use double pointers when you work on pointers that are changed in other places of your application. You might also find double pointers to be a must when you deal with hardware that returns and address to you.