# Two dimension char array initialization C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

According to this response [pointers to pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580761/why-use-double-pointer-or-why-use-pointers-to-pointers)

```
char[] = char *p
char[][] = char **p
```

But, when I initialize an array of strings with the next two forms

```
char **p = {"Hello", "World"};
char p[][] = {"Hello", "World"};
```

The compiler shows me some Error.

> [Error] array type has incomplete element type

But with

```
char *matriz[] = {"Hello", "World"};
```

There is no warning. I'm new in C language, and I'm very confused.

Comment: C, sorry I will remove the C++ tag

Comment: You cannot have dynamic-sized arrays in `C`, and that's not a warning, it is an ERROR

Comment: The answer in the link does not state what you are supposedly quoting!!!

Comment: What you quote ,states that `arrays and pointers are same` ? Is that what you meant?

Comment: I understand that if I have `char arr[]`, then `arr = &arr[0]`, sorry but I'm very confused

Comment: wt is your compiler? Is it gcc? I'm not getting any error with gcc. http://goo.gl/SREx43

Comment: With the pointer notation, I get same warnings as you, with `char p[][] = {"Hello", "World"};`, I get the error

Comment: @GargAnkit there is no dynamic array necessary; dimensions and sizes are statically known at compile time.

Comment: Any document that equates `char[][]` with `char **` is not going to be dreadfully helpful; the two are quite different.  In fact, `char[]` is not the same as `char *` either, but when you use those notations in the parameter list for a function, they are equivalent (that is: `void something(char data[])` and `void something(char *data)` _are_ equivalent in this one important context).  However, `void otherthing(char data[][10])` and `void otherthing(char **data)` are not equivalent at all.

Comment: Having looked at the other SO question, I don't see where an answer makes the equation you infer from it — which is a relief since it is an SO question.

Comment: The array of arrays `char ary[3][2]` decays to a pointer to the first element of the array, which will have the type `char (*)[2]` (pointer to array of char). No further decay can occur. This means `char **p;` and `char (*ary_ptr)[2];` are incompatible declarations, and `char **p;` and `char array[3][2];` are also incompatible declarations by extension of the concept. Whoever equated `char[][]` and `char**` is incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No an array of array is not the same as a double pointer. You really should read that up, there are a lot of FAQ and answers around.

Then the error that you receive is for the doubly empty `[][]`. In C, when you declare an array with `[]` the compiler tries to compute the size of the array from the initializer. This only works for one `[]`. For the second you *have to* give a length. Something like

```
char p[][7] = {"Hello", "World"};
```

should work. For your first form

```
char **p
```

this declares a pointer to pointer, so in particular a pointer. Pointers can't be initialized with two items, they need just one, and that should itself be of the correct pointer type or convert to it.