# request for member `'next'` in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, linked-list

Why am I getting this error?:

```
request for member 'next' in something not a structure or union|
```

in this lines:

```
 if(*head->next == NULL){
        *head->next = newNode;
```

**Error**:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Lab9 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c||In function 'insertNode':|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c|38|error: request for member 'next' in something not a structure or union|
C:\Users\s\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c|39|error: request for member 'next' in something not a structure or union|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c|44|error: request for member 'next' in something not a structure or union|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c|48|warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c|50|warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c|51|warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c|56|warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wreturn-type]|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c||In function 'printList':|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c|58|error: request for member 'next' in something not a structure or union|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c|63|error: request for member 'next' in something not a structure or union|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c|65|warning: implicit declaration of function 'print' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c|65|error: expected ')' before 'current'|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c|66|warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]|
C:\Users\shohi_000\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c|72|warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wreturn-type]|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c||In function 'deleteList':|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c|74|error: request for member 'next' in something not a structure or union|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c|74|error: expected statement before ')' token|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c|79|error: 'else' without a previous 'if'|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c|80|error: request for member 'next' in something not a structure or union|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c|83|warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c||In function 'main':|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c|98|warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c|99|warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c|101|warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c|101|warning: unused variable 'maxValue' [-Wunused-variable]|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c|98|warning: unused variable 'seedNum' [-Wunused-variable]|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c||In function 'printList':|
C:\Users\\C_Projects\Lab9\main.c|69|warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]|
||=== Build failed: 10 error(s), 14 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

**Code**

```
//Defines the struct of Node
typedef struct NodeStruct{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
}Node;
//The function insert a newly created Node into its proper position
//The list will be sorted in ascending order
void insertNode(Node **head, int data){
    //Create a new Node with the given num
    Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data = data;

    //Check if the list is empty
    if(*head->next == NULL){
        *head->next = newNode; //point head's next to the newNode
        newNode->next = NULL;
    }
    //If the list is not empty, then insert the newNode into its proper position
    else{
        Node *current = *head->next; //starts from the very first element(after dummy node!)
        Node *previous = NULL; //previous is needed for storing the previous node before exiting the loop
        while(current != NULL && current->data < data){
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
        previous->next = newNode; //place the node between previous and current
        newNode->next = current;
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //If argc < 4 then quit the program
    if(argc < 4){
        badProgram();
    }
    else{
        Node *head = dummyNode();
        int seedNum = argv[1]; //gets the integer for seeding the random generator
        int totalNums = argv[2]; //gets the total number of random numbers
        srand(totalNums); //input into the srand()
        int maxValue = argv[3]; //maximum possible value

        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < totalNums; i++){
            int num = rand(); //generates a random number
            fprintf(stdout, "%d", num); //outputs the number to the screen
            insertNode(&head, num);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Share the error that you are getting..

Comment: if((*head)->next == NULL){
          (*head)->next = newNode;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct NodeStruct{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
}Node;
//The function insert a newly created Node into its proper position
//The list will be sorted in ascending order
void insertNode(Node **head, int data){
    //Create a new Node with the given num
    Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next=NULL;
    //Check if the list is empty
    if(head == NULL){
        head = newNode; //point head's next to the newNode
       // head->next = NULL;
    }
    //If the list is not empty, then insert the newNode into its proper position
    else{
        Node *current = head; //starts from the very first element(after dummy node!)
        Node *previous = NULL; //previous is needed for storing the previous node before exiting the loop
        while(current != NULL && current->data < data){
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
        previous->next = newNode; //place the node between previous and current
        newNode->next = current;
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //If argc < 4 then quit the program
    if(argc < 4){
        badProgram();
    }
    else{
        Node *head = dummyNode();
        int seedNum = argv[1]; //gets the integer for seeding the random generator
        int totalNums = argv[2]; //gets the total number of random numbers
        srand(totalNums); //input into the srand()
        int maxValue = argv[3]; //maximum possible value

        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < totalNums; i++){
            int num = rand(); //generates a random number
            fprintf(stdout, "%d", num); //outputs the number to the screen
            insertNode(&head, num);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Your code had some problems 
first of: head is already a pointer node that should point to the first node as shown below

---

**|head|**-->**firstNode**-->**secondNode**, and so on

But, from the code fragment given  below

```
if(*head->next == NULL){
        *head->next = newNode; //point head's next to the newNode
        newNode->next = NULL;
    }
```

I get to see something else happening, you are trying to store the newNode's address to the address of the head**(not the address that the head stores)**. The address of the head is actually stored by no variable. **This could be the major reason that you're getting the error**
Hopefully, I have corrected the code from its syntactical errors yet the methods possibly have some undefined reference. May be you have defined the method somewhere.
Hope you have understood the answer

**Thankyou**

Answer (score 0):

it has to do with this:

```
**head
```

then you do this

```
*head->next
```

you are still pointing to the pointer that points to head.

here is complete code:

```
void insertNode(Node *head, int data){
    //Create a new Node with the given num
    Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data = data;

    //Check if the list is empty
    if(head->next == NULL){
        head->next = newNode; //point head's next to the newNode
        newNode->next = NULL;
    }
    //If the list is not empty, then insert the newNode into its proper position
    else{
        Node *current = head->next; //starts from the very first element(after dummy node!)
        Node *previous = NULL; //previous is needed for storing the previous node before exiting the loop
        while(current != NULL && current->data < data){
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
        previous->next = newNode; //place the node between previous and current
        newNode->next = current;
    }
}
```

your function should simply be

```
void insertNode(Node *head, int data)
```

Comment: What do you mean? And how?

Comment: Last question, @GRC: in C, when do I have to use dereferencing, i.e. `**` ?

Comment: Double pointers are headaches for many in C I am not exception :) Maybe this will help you a bit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580761/why-use-double-pointer-or-why-use-pointers-to-pointers

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the expression `*head->next`.  Since `->` has higher precedence than `*`, this is equivalent to `*(head->next)`.  What you want is `(*head)->next`, so you need the parentheses.