# C pointer vs pointer to pointer - what's the proper usage?

Tags: c, pointers

What is the difference between a pointer and a double pointer

Why would the second one ever be used?

```
char *a; //Points to a char
char **b; //Why doesn't this also point char
```

Answer (score 2):

A "double pointer" is just a pointer to another pointer. In your example, a pointer that points to a pointer that points to a char.

EDIT
Actually this was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580761/why-use-double-pointer-or-why-use-pointers-to-pointers).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me tell you, *double pointer* is not a correct nomenclature for a *pointer to pointer*. At times, they can mean different things (*double pointer == pointer to a `double`*) and create confusions.

A pointer points to a variable or a function. Now, a pointer itself **is** a variable, so there can be another pointer which points to the *pointer variable*. The later is called a pointer-to-pointer.

So, in case of

```
char *a;
```

`a` is a pointer which points to a `char`.

Thus,

```
char **b;
```

`b` is a pointer which points to a `char *` and hence, they are different.

You can write

```
b = &a;
```

Answer (score 0):

`b` is a pointer to a pointer to a `char`. More common than most double pointers, since `char *` is typically used to reference strings, and a `char **` will point to that.