# Difficulty in understanding the pointers output

Tags: c, pointers

Please have a look at code below  :

```
#include <stdio.h>   
void main()
{
    int a=30;
    int *var=&a;
    Change(&var);
    printf("%d %d",*var,a);
}

int Change(int**ptr)
{
    **ptr=40;
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int a=30;
    int *var=&a;
    Change(var);
    printf("%d %d",*var,a);
}

int Change( int *ptr)
{
    *ptr=40;
}
```

The output from both programs is `40 40`

We are passing the copy of address of var so why it is reflected in actual main function and producing output `40 40`?

Why both of these programs are producing same output?

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: Which one of the two programs you don't understand?

Comment: Both of them @MichaelWalz

Comment: See [What should `main()` return in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/) — though this is tangential to the issue being discussed in the question.

Comment: Actually i'm having problem in understanding the double pointer used  in the first program .what is the main difference between these two program ?

Comment: `&var` passes the address of `var` and Change uses double pointer because, `var` is pointing to address of `a`. So, Derefrencing single pointer on `&var` (address of var) will point to the value stored in `var` i.e., `a`'s address, so again derefrencing it, will point to the value 30.

Comment: What output did you expect, and why?

Comment: The more interesting case is where you dynamically allocate storage for `var` in `Change`. Then the pointer/double-pointer distinction, and why?, becomes instantly clear.

Comment: take a look here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580761/why-use-double-pointer-or-why-use-pointers-to-pointers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both programs are equivalent. In first one, you passing pointer to pointer (i.e. address of pointer variable), and then dereferencing it twice. In second one, you are are just passing pointer (i.e. address of actual variable) and dereferencing it once.

Comment: they are equivalent. But: in the first, you could change *ptr to point to a different int, and get a printf like " 30 40 ", which is not possible in the second program, where the 2 values printf'ed will always be the same, since in Change() you always work on a

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you need the following illustration to get the answer on your q:

[image: Pointers Diagram]

Answer (score 1):

The output is the same because you write `40` via the same pointer to `int`. In the second case you pass pointer-to-int, which you successfully dereference with `*` operator and obtain lvalue with type `int`, to which you then write `40`. In the first case you pass pointer-to-pointer-to-int. And then you do double dereferencing: `**ptr` or the same as `*(*ptr)`. Inner `*` is applied first and makes the expression with type pointer-to-int inside braces, and that pointer-to-int is the same as was passed to `Change()` in the second case. And at the end - outer `*` works just like for the second case.

Answer (score 1):

`&var` passes the address of `var` and `Change` uses double pointer because, `var` is pointing to address of `a`. So, Derefrencing single pointer on `&var` (address of var) will point to the value stored in `var` i.e., `a`'s address, so again derefrencing it, will point to the value of `a` i.e., `30`.

For single pointer `Change`, I think, you should figure that out now from the above details.