# What's the meaning of "int * * k"?

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-to-pointer

I am beginner of C Programming language. I saw a code on the book:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int * * k, *a, b=100;

    a = &b;
    k = &a;
    printf("%d\n",* * k);
}
```

I don't know the meaning of `int * *k`. Is that a integer pointer or value? what will it point to? what will it contains/store? what's the use of this variable? How can I understand this expression?

Comment: It's two level pointer dereferencing.

Comment: "k" is a pointer that point to an integer pointer

Answer (score 8):

```
int **k
```

`k` is a **pointer to pointer to int(double pointer)** and holds an address of some other pointer variable.

In your example:

```
 int  b = 100;   /* 'b' is an int, initialized to value 100 */
 int *a = &b;  /* a is a pointer-to-int*/
 int **k = &a; /* k is a pointer-to-pointer-to-int */
```

See below picture for better understanding:

[image: ptr]

Comment: Thank you. can you tell me in what situation this pointer-to-a-pointer will be used?

Comment: @BingSun When we want a list of words (a sentence), We  can use that.

Comment: @BingSun See stack overflow question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580761/why-use-double-pointer-or-why-use-pointers-to-pointers

Comment: I think I got it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`int** k` is a pointer to an int pointer.

It stores a memory address, in that memory address there another memory address in which some integer value is stored.

Answer (score 1):

It's called double pointer. It can be used to store address from single pointer.

You can also create triple pointer to store address from double pointer.

Example: `int ***k;`

Answer (score 1):

This is called pointer to a pointer.

Here, the output for **k is 100, the value of b.

```
  *(*k) = *(a) = *(address of b) = value of b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
*k
```

means some code will get a value from address k later.

```
*(*k)
```

means some code will get a value from address (*k) later.

```
int **k
```

means `k` is intended to be used for address dereferencing for integer use but with a second level. Having this `*` character just behind a variable name at its definition, makes it a pointer. So k is  a pointer to a pointer to an integer.

To get the value of cell that a pointer points to,

```
*k
```

is used just like in the definition. Then when it is a second-order pointer then

```
**k
```

is used to get its pointed value.