# is g_free needed after declaring gchar?

Tags: c, malloc, gtk3, free

I am a beginner using GTK+ with C to write a small app. I am setting up a filter for `GtkTreeView`, with the display func as below, mostly copied from [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeModelFilter.html#gtk-tree-model-filter-set-visible-func:).

```
static gboolean filter_func (GtkTreeModel *model, GtkTreeIter *row, gpointer data) {
  // if search string is empty return TRUE

  gchar *titleId, *region, *name;
  gtk_tree_model_get (model, row, 0, &titleId, 1, &region, 2, &name, -1);

  // get search string
  if (strstr (titleId, "search text here") != NULL) {
    return TRUE;
  }

  g_free (titleId);
  g_free (region);
  g_free (name);

  return FALSE;
}
```

I have assumed so far that `free()` is needed with `malloc()` and reading https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Memory-Allocation.html tells me:

> It's important to match `g_malloc()` (and wrappers such as `g_new()`)
>   with `g_free()`

So if that is the case, then why is `g_free()` being called here? The reason why this is important is because this code will be called thousands of times per character typed in the search.

Comment: You didn't copy properly. In the text you linked `g_free` is also called in case `TRUE` is returned. Your code creates a memory leak in case the condition is met.

Comment: @Gerhardh right you are, thank you.

Comment: Because `gtk_tree_model_get` is calling `g_malloc`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes.

From [the docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeModel.html#gtk-tree-model-get).

> Returned values with type G_TYPE_OBJECT have to be unreferenced, values with type G_TYPE_STRING or G_TYPE_BOXED have to be freed. Other values are passed by value.

`G_TYPE_STRING` being "*the fundamental type corresponding to nul-terminated C strings*" which is `gchar`.

The "*Reading data from a GtkTreeModel*" example in [the docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeModel.html#gtk-tree-model-get) makes it very clear.

```
   gchar *str_data;
   gint   int_data;

   // Make sure you terminate calls to gtk_tree_model_get() with a “-1” value
   gtk_tree_model_get (list_store, &iter,
                       STRING_COLUMN, &str_data,
                       INT_COLUMN, &int_data,
                       -1);

   // Do something with the data
   g_print ("Row %d: (%s,%d)\n",
            row_count, str_data, int_data);
   g_free (str_data);
```

> *So if that is the case, then why is g_free() being called here?*

Because `gtk_tree_model_get` is doing the `malloc` for you. It is [a common use of a double pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5580790/14660) to pass memory allocated inside a function to the caller.

`str_data` is passed to `gtk_tree_model_get` as a `g_char**` so it can modify where `str_data` points. `gtk_tree_model_get` allocates the memory, obtaining a `g_char*`. It assigns that pointer to `*str_data` to "return" the memory back to you. Then you access the string as `*str_data`.

```
void get_tree_model_get_simplified(g_char** str_data)
{
    *str_data = g_malloc(...);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The pointers there are freed because `gtk_tree_model_get` mallocs pointers to strings and sets the pointers provided to point to those strings. [function reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkTreeModel.html#gtk-tree-model-get)

Note where it says "Values with type `G_TYPE_STRING` need to be freed"