# Why do I have to declare pointers this way?

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax

I've been practicing by looking at others code and I cannot understand the following concept:

```
int *ptr2int = &varInt;
int **ptr2ptr = &ptr2int;
int ***ptr2ptr2 = &ptr2ptr;
```

Why the first pointer declaration uses one *, the second uses two and the third uses three? How do pointers work exactly and what's * doing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580761/why-use-double-pointer-or-why-use-pointers-to-pointers

Comment: The number of asterisks indicates a difference in type. `int*` can point to a non-pointer variable, `int**` can point to a pointer variable(int*) and `int***` can point to a pointer to a pointer. I wouldn't worry about `int***`, it's practically non-existent in any production code and even `int**` is extremely rare.

Comment: Not sure this will help or not. How I digest this concept is: I think of value as thing lets say ball and I put it in box which is memory address and when there is one * in pointer that means ball is wrapped in one box when two * are there then 2 boxes and so on. Each inner box is value for the outer box and outer box is address for inner one. This way compiler get to know how many deep a code is going to wrap or unwrap things. Not sure I am correct or not.

Answer (score 3):

The first pointer is a pointer to an `int`, so that's one `*`.

The second pointer is a pointer to a pointer to an `int`. So that 2 `**`.

Same for the third one.

A pointer represent the address of an object, in the first case the address of an `int`. Then you can have an address to an address pointing to an `int`.

etc.

Comment: Actually, the second pointer is a pointer to a pointer to an `int`. It's two levels of indirections, not three.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, copy mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The `*`, in this context, means that the variable type is a "point of". 

`varInt` is an `int`, so `ptr2int` that points to its address is a "pointer to int", or `int *`.

`ptr2ptr` points to the address of `ptr2int`, so it's a "pointer to a pointer to int", or `int **`.

`ptr2ptr2` points to the address of `ptr2int`, so its a "pointer to a pointer to a pointer to int", or `int ***`.

Answer (score 0):

If there is exist at least one asterisk before the name of a variable then the variable is a pointer. The only things make pointer different regular variable is pointers are only used to store address( of an variable). 
Let look at below example:

```
int     *ptr2int = &varInt; //line 1
int*    *ptr2ptr = &ptr2int;//line 2
int**   *ptr2ptr2 = &ptr2ptr;//line 3
```

I have separated the asterisks for you to easily imagine.

- At first line, because exist one asterisk before `ptr2int` so `ptr2int` will be a pointer, the ptr2int will be used to point to `int` variable(`ptr2int` will store address of an `int` value, in this case is address of `varInt`).
- At second line, because exist one asterisk before `ptr2ptr` so `ptr2ptr` will be a pointer, but the pointer is not same with the pointer at the first line, the pointer at this line will be used to point to an `int*` variable( address of `int*` variable, in this case is address of `ptr2int`).
- And so on for the third line, because exist one asterisk before `ptr2ptr2` so it is a pointer, and the pointer will be used to store address of an `int**` variable. `ptr2ptr` is `int**` type.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0; // integer type
```

If I want to *point* to `i` I need a *pointer to integer* type:

```
int* ip; // pointer to integer type
```

If I want to *point* to `ip` I need a *pointer to (pointer to integer)* type:

```
int** ipp; // pointer to (pointer to integer) type
```

That's needed because `ip` is type `int*`. So a *pointer* to that is `int**`.

Whenever you need a *pointer to* a given type, you use a `*` in the declaration. Even if that type is *already* a pointer type.

So to point to a value, you need `int*`.

So to point to a pointer to a value, you need `int**`.

So to point to a pointer to a pointer to a value, you need `int***`.

So to point to a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a value, you need `int****`.

etc...