# I don't understand this code arrays and pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I learned pointers and arrays already but I don't know what ** or && is used for and when trying to understand this line im not sure what this is.

```
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int n, m, option, row, col, flagCount = 0;
    char **flags, **board;
```

im not sure what's being declared in the 4th row also those pointers at list I think they are are later in the program being sent to this function .

```
char **creatArray(int n)
```

what is this (**) used for in the function type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use double pointer? or Why use pointers to pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580761/why-use-double-pointer-or-why-use-pointers-to-pointers)

Comment: I would edit my post but I can't sorry, its telling me that there's spam from my network something like that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you use a pointer '*' you can create for example an array when you allocate memory for multiple chars. Example char *word = malloc(10*sizeof(char)). Your word has now space for 10 chars. When you want to create a sentence you need multiple words so you can create a two dimensional array. You can say char *sentence = malloc(10*sizeof(word)).

In c double pointer are often used to create a two dimensional array.

When your function create a new game board of size n*n then it will return the array. 
So for example you call char **board = **newArray(n);

In c you can create an array like char array[] or you can create an like char *array. This is the same because an array in C is a pointer to the first element of the array. But the problem is you can't return an array like this from a function you need to return the pointer. So char[] function() is not working you need to say char *function(). And this is the case in your example you create a new two dimensaional array for your board and return the pointer to the first element (pointer) of the array that is why you call your function char** and not char[][].

Comment: I know what its used for (basically a board for a game) but im more confused about why its in the function name

Comment: When you create a game board with this function I think you pass the argument n to create a n * n sized board. So your function create a new Array/gameBoard and return this game board as a two dimensional array. So the code should look something like char **board = createArray(n)

Comment: yes that pretty much what I figured it did except that this is the line board = creatArray(n); so why are there no ** here?

Comment: and also why would I need a pointer to a pointer array to make a board game. this isn't my code I just needed help with understanding it but why now use a normal two dimension array?

Comment: You need a pointer to a pointer array because you need the two dimensions

Comment: can't you make a two dimensional array that has nothing to do with pointers?

Comment: No you can't. When you create an array in c you allocate coherently memory. For example when you create an array for 10 integers you allocate coherently memory with enough space for 10 integers an your array is a pointer to the first address of this array when you call array[1] c calculate the first address plus the size of one integer to get your second value from the array. In short in c your array is a pointer to the first array Element so you can't create an array without a pointer

Comment: You simply simplify to much. An array is not a pointer and a pointer is not an array. It's  just that arrays in most cases are decayed to a pointer to their 1st element.

Comment: @yadinmeretzki: "*can't you make a two dimensional array that has nothing to do with pointers*" sure. For a 2D `char` array with 3x5 elements just define: `char array2D[3][5]`.

Comment: @alk it's not simplify it's the Definition of c. An array is a pointer to the first address of coherently allocated memory

Comment: @alk you can do that as i mentioned in my answer but the problem is you can't return this from your function you need a pointer you can't return an array.

Comment: "*you can't return this from your function you need a pointer you can't return an array.*" Correct. And this BTW is a prefect prove for that arrays and pointers are different beasts. ;)

Comment: Another thing with you answer: Assuming `newArray(n)` returned `char**` then this `char **board = **newArray(n);`  won't compile nicely.

Comment: Also following this advice "*In c double pointer are often used to create a two dimensional array.*" you do not get a real array. But a jagged (aka scattered) "array", that is you do not get a continuous region of memory, but several separated regions.

Comment: @alk they are not exact the same no but I think this is not part of the question

Comment: @alk i think the correct syntax is char **board = newArray(n). If this is false please correct me

Comment: @alk since I am programming C this is the most useful pro of using pointer to pointer. And as far as I know the only way to create a dynamic array in C

Answer (score 2):

`*` is a pointer type, `**` is a pointer type to a pointer, for example: `int* p;`, meaning that `p` is a pointer type that points to `int`, and if you need a pointer type to this `p` pointer, you can do the following definition: `int** test = &p;` At this point `test` is a pointer to `p`, its type is `int**`.

Answer (score 1):

char *flag;
it means that flag is a pointer which will hold the address of character data type

char **flag;
it means that flag is a pointer which will hold the address of a "POINTER" which is pointer to a character data type
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPFmP.png)

Comment: what about the function name?

Comment: @yadinmeretzki: `char ** createArray()` returns a pointer to a pointer to `char`.