# i`m making code tree, data structure. However, there is an error in the printing process

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, tree, nodes

There seems to be no problem in the insertion process, but only the root node is output when printing. What is the problem?
**text error**

1. n = (node*)m(sizeof(node))
2. print , scan

**Data structure, tree**

```
    struct node {
    int data;
    node* l, *r;
};
```

```
node* Insert(node* st, int item)
{
    node* n, * p; p = st;
    n = (node*)m(sizeof(node));
    n->data = item; n->l = NULL; n->r = NULL;

    if (st == NULL) {
        return n;
    }

    while (p != NULL) {
        if (p->data > item) {
            p = p->l;
        }
        else p = p->r;
    }
    p = n;

    return st;

}
```

```
node* st = NULL;
    node* a = NULL;
    while (1) {
        print("\n트리 1)삽입 2)삭제 3)전위순회 출력 4) 종료 "); scan("%d", &menu);
        if (menu == 4) break;

        switch (menu) {
        case 1:
            print("삽입할 값 입력 : "); scan("%d", &item);
            st = Insert(st, item);
            break;
        case 2:
            a = st;
            print("%d", a->data); a = a->l; print("%d", a->data); a = st->r; print("%d", a->data);
            break;
```

Comment: 1) n = (node*)m(sizeof(node)) -> n=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node))
2) print -> printf , scan -> scanf

Comment: If you get a syntax error reported by your compiler, please show the exact message.

Comment: No. There are no syntax errors caused by the compiler. When the code was uploaded to stackoverflow, an error occurred in typedef, variable name, etc.

Comment: You mean that "I don't know why that syntax is an error on here" is not related to a compilation error?

Comment: Sorry, Main Question is "There seems to be no problem in the insertion process, but only the root node is output when printing. What is the problem?"

Comment: If there are no syntax errors, then why do you mention a syntax error in your question?? Please [edit] and make that clear

Comment: Do you **really** have a macro `m` to replace `malloc` and `print` ro replace `printf`? That is asking for trouble. Lots of trouble.

Comment: Your code is not a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Please add the missing code to allow us compiling the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting aside the syntax and style issues, I noticed a logical error in your `Insert` function. It appears you're implementing a binary search tree and you are walking the tree correctly. However, you're not actually inserting into the tree because the node p does not point into the tree; it's simply a copy of the node.

Consider what happens when we have the below tree:

```
     1
   /   \
 NULL  NULL
```

Let's insert 2 into the tree.

```
Insert(st, 2)
Step 1: p is a COPY of the root of st, which is node 1
     1 ==  p
   /   \
  NULL NULL

Step 2: Because p->data == 1 < 2, we move to the right and hit NULL
     1
   /   \
  NULL NULL == p

Now we assign p to the new node n:
     1
   /   \
  NULL  NULL; p = n
```

As you can see in the above, we didn't actually link the new node to the root; all we did was traverse to the correct location in the tree, but then assigned the new node `n` to `p`, which doesn't actually write into the tree; it just gives `p` the address of the node pointed to by `n`. It doesn't actually change the address of the node we'd like to change.

One solution (which seems to be your intention) is to have `p` be a pointer to a node pointer (`node **`). You can find more details about double pointers in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580761/why-use-double-indirection-or-why-use-pointers-to-pointers).

Below is a visualization if we have `p` point to each node.

```
Insert(st, 2)
Step 1: Let p be a pointer to the root of st, which is node 1
     1 <- p
   /   \
  NULL NULL

Step 2: Because (*p)->data == 1 < 2, we move to the right (p = &((*p)->right)) and have *p == NULL
     1
   /   \
  NULL NULL <- p

Now we have p point to to the new node n: *p = n
     1
   /   \
  NULL  n

And have now added n into our tree successfully.
```