# How can pointers be allocated in main function?

Tags: c

I just started learning the programming language C and am having a problem while solving 1 exercise below.

Write a program that dynamically allocates 10 bytes of memory for a pointer, with the provided function template as follows:
bool allocate10Bytes(uint8_t *outPtr);

- outPtr: output pointer
- return: true: If the allocation is successful.
  false: If the allocation failed.

I tried with the following code but the pointer in main function is still not allocated.

```
bool allocate10Bytes(uint8_t* outPtr)
{
    outPtr = (uint8_t*)malloc(10 * sizeof(uint8_t));

    if (outPtr == NULL) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t* p = NULL;

    bool success = allocate10Bytes(p);
    
    if (success) free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please note that It can't be both C and C++ at once.

Comment: There’s no way to get the value of the pointer to the allocated memory back to `main` with the function signature that’s given.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5580790) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26004257) will help you.

Comment: @rawrex I'm sorry for that.

Comment: Impossible. `allocate10Bytes` either needs to return a `uint8_t*` or accept a `unit8_t**` as an argument.

Comment: Where did this requirement come from? Because it is broken.

Comment: [Is this you?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68537895/write-a-program-that-dynamically-allocates-10-bytes-of-memory-for-a-pointer)  (10K only)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code aimed to change a pointer argument's value since arguments are passed by value, the code have changed the local value `outPtr`'s value, not the one in `main`

To pass a pointer as an argument and change the pointer's value in callee, we have only one choice in C : to pass a pointer to the pointer

```cpp
bool allocate10Bytes(uint8_t** outPtr) {
  *outPtr = malloc(10 * sizeof(uint8_t));

  if (*outPtr == NULL) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

int main(void) {
  uint8_t* p = NULL;

  bool success = allocate10Bytes(&p);

  if (success) free(p);
  return 0;
}
```

For code smells: it's bad to use a magic number `10` in the code, it would be much better to add a macro or constant here.

---

If the function prototype must be `bool allocate10Bytes(uint8_t* outPtr)`, then we need some ugly casting here. I don't think it's a good exercise problem, maybe your teacher is doing something wrong.

```cpp
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
bool allocate10Bytes(uint8_t* outPtr) {
  uint8_t** outPtr1 = (uint8_t**)(outPtr);
  *outPtr1 = malloc(10 * sizeof(uint8_t));

  if (*outPtr1 == NULL) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

int main(void) {
  uint8_t* p = NULL;

  bool success = allocate10Bytes((uint8_t*)&p);

  if (success) free(p);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No need to cast the pointer

Comment: `*outPtr = malloc(10 * sizeof(uint8_t));` could be cleaned up a bit. Use the type of `outPtr` in `sizeof`

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin This exercise does not allow changing the input parameters of the function. The function parameter must be uint8_t* outPtr.

Comment: @Justin If the function prototype must be `bool allocate10Bytes(uint8_t* outPtr)`, then we need some ugly casting here. I don't think it's a good exercise problem, maybe your teacher is doing something wrong.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin I think so, too. Thanks for the great advice!

Comment: @Justin the requirement is broken, your teacher should be fired.