# The difference between passing double pointer and pointer as an argument

Tags: c++, pointers, leveldb

1. pass * as a function parameter

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A {

 public: 
  A() {}

};


class B : public A{
 public:
  B() {}

};

void foo(A* a) {
 a = new B();

}

void ff() {
  A a;
  foo(&a);
}
```

2. pass ** as a function parameter

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A {

 public: 
  A() {}

};


class B : public A{
 public:
  B() {}

};

void foo(A** a) {
 *a = new B();

}

void ff() {
  A* a;
  foo(&a);
}
```

When I see leveldb, I am in a puzzle about this.

The specific code is the following.

https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/master/db/db_impl.cc#L1537

I think it's ok to use `FileLock lock`

Then pass `&lock` to `LockFile(const std::string& filename, FileLock* lock)`

`LockFile` function is [this](https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/master/util/env_posix.cc#L628)

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why use double indirection? or Why use pointers to pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580761/why-use-double-indirection-or-why-use-pointers-to-pointers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Passing double pointer and just a pointer are not the same

```cpp
void foo(A* a) {
 a = new B();

}
```

1. Change an input pointer to another value. The result will not reflect in the callee `ff()`.
   It's merely change the argument.

```cpp
void foo(A** a) {
 *a = new B();

}
```

2. Change a pointer to another pointer and change the value, which is "the another pointer", of this pointer points to . The result will reflect in `ff()`

According to the `ff()`, I assume you have a follow up question which need to operate `a` after `foo()` is called. So second one might be a proper way.

For `FileLock`, I believe you're referring to this [implementation](https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/f57513a1d6c99636fc5b710150d0b93713af4e43/util/env_posix.cc#L628).

It's using double pointer because it wants to replace the entire content of `FileLock`.

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Gfhzxn3n5)

### Followup: Why it chose using double pointer instead of pass by reference?

Because reference is not possible to be replaced, my assumption is that it chose it chose to replace the whole content which is simpler than make the implemention complex for re-initialization.

Comment: just  use `FileLock lock` and pass `&lock` to `LockFile(const std::string& filename, FileLock* lock)` also can replace the entire content of `FileLock`

Comment: @stackover Have you tried that? You can only change the value of the argument pointer. Replacing the argument doesn't reflect to callee.

Comment: I don't understand why I was so confused about this in the first place. uhhhh

Comment: @stackover I face palm all the time when I found the solution. It's good to take a walk when you can't figure out something :)